# UnoPlatform -The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: prism, uno-platform

i am using Uno prism template for my Uno platform App. After making an async call in UWP app. i.e.

```cs
var content = await GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync(graphAPIEndpoint,authResult.AccessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

whenever RaisePropertyChanged() method hits I am getting following error=>
{"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"}

Git repo=> https://github.com/avikeid2007/Repayabl

File=> https://github.com/avikeid2007/Repayabl/blob/dev/RepayablClient/RepayablClient.Shared/ViewModels/LoginViewModel.cs#L131

Comment: Did you try your code removing the `ConfigureAwait(false);` from the `GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync` method? I believe your problem could be there.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment, the problem here is the use of `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

With `ConfigureAwait(false)` you're telling the compiler, 'after this awaited method executes, don't bother coming back to the current context, I'm good.' In some cases this can be an appropriate optimization, or even a guard against deadlocking, particularly when you're writing a class library.

However you normally shouldn't use it in callbacks from the UI thread, like this case. In UWP and indeed most UI frameworks, you can only modify the UI from the main UI thread, otherwise you will get exactly the error you mention. So you **need** to be returned to the same context after the awaited method completes.

**TLDR:** Remove `ConfigureAwait(false)`, don't use it in `async` methods invoked from the UI thread.